# Search Console API by curl

Tags: php, api, google-api-php-client, google-search-console

I am using google console search API by curl but i am getting the error "code": 401, "message": "Login Required" . What are other parameters needs to be consider in URL in order to get authorized success response form google console search API. Please let me know how can i implement Google Console Search API.

http://prntscr.com/buuaqc